# What can I use to switch a circuit from one load to another?

Tags: electrical

I am using an existing 120V 20amp circuit to feed a work shed. I want to switch between the work shed and the existing light/relay use. The lighting is not in use but could be in the future.  I want to isolate one from the other. I can use a simple SPDT 30amp rated switch but am looking for something more substantial that doesn't resemble a standard light switch. Any suggestions? TIA

Comment: A transfer switch?  One or the other type.

Comment: Why do you want the lights to never be on when the work shed is on, and vice versa?

Comment: Because I dont want to dig up the details on the relays and the lights to determine the amp draw and its a long run. I would rather just shut it off and then only worry about what Im running in the shop.

Comment: how big are these lights? for a shed? change them to LED bulbs and the amp draw to light up your shed is way less than 1 amp, no?

Answer (score 3):

From an electrical point of view, a standard three-way switch is a single-pole double-throw (SPDT) switch, and could be used to switch 120V power between two loads. If you have a 20A breaker in this circuit, a 20A switch will suffice.

The next owner of your house (and their inspector) may not be happy with this, though. There are safety risks in letting someone remotely remove power from a work area. And I have no idea whether code anticipated this arrangement.

Seriously, I'd suggest spending a bit more and going with the standard solution of dropping in a new breaker and circuit.

Answer (score 1):

All the most serious options I can think of will be very expensive, a headache, or both. Your best bet is probably just to put a switch inline with each load. Use switches of a different color than the rest of the house so it's obvious. Only turn on one switch at a time.

If you do decide you want to hunt down something more substantial, double pole double throw switches do exist. The typical brands have them for in the $60 territory in my searching.